# how to set different font sizes in the same html header?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

I want to create an html header as follows

`"Version1: (10.3.4)  vs Version2: (10.3.4)"`

and I want the version number be smaller than the words `"Version1"` and `"Version2"`

how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you need. No special coding required.

```html
<h1>Version1: <small>(10.3.4)</small> vs Version2: <small>(10.3.4)</small></h1>
```

Comment: I wanted to create this html dynamically using `gagawa`




I tried:

H3 h3 = new H3().appendText("BaseLine " + new Small().appendText(globalSettings.blServerVersion) + " vs FreshRun " + new Small().appendText(globalSettings
                .freshRunServerVersion));

and I get:

`BaseLine com.hp.gagawa.java.elements.Small@68c697ec vs FreshRun com.hp.gagawa.java.elements.Small@1ab4d8f4`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the version number inside a <kbd>span</kbd> and give it a different font-size.

```css
span {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>"Version1: <span>(10.3.4)</span>  vs Version2: <span>(10.3.4)</span>"</h1>
```

Comment: Although this looks better.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Version1:<span style="font-size:10px;"> (10.3.4)</span>  vs Version2: <span style="font-size:10px;">(10.3.4)</span>
```

Comment: Please avoid inline styles.

Comment: Of course, this is just an example to present a solution.